# Turn while loop number game into a do while loop number game

Tags: java

I made a number game using while loops but I am told I am supposed to do with with do while instead. I was wondering how I could transfer it from this format to do while.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class SS_Un6As2 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   int guess = 0;

   int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() *100) +1;

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   boolean running = true;

       while(running){
           System.out.println("Guess your number");
          guess = scan.nextInt();
           if(guess == randomNumber) {
                System.out.println("You are correct");
             break;
           }
           else if (guess > randomNumber){
               System.out.println("Too high.");
           }              
           else if (guess < randomNumber){
               System.out.println("Too low");
          }
           else {
               System.out.println("Try again");

           }
       }

   System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Solution to your problem**

```
while(running){
       System.out.println("Guess your number");
      guess = scan.nextInt();
       if(guess == randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("You are correct");
         break;
       }
       else if (guess > randomNumber){
           System.out.println("Too high.");
       }              
       else if (guess < randomNumber){
           System.out.println("Too low");
      }
       else {
           System.out.println("Try again");

       }
   }
```

Becomes

```
    do {
       System.out.println("Guess your number");
      guess = scan.nextInt();
       if(guess == randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("You are correct");
         break;
       }
       else if (guess > randomNumber){
           System.out.println("Too high.");
       }              
       else if (guess < randomNumber){
           System.out.println("Too low");
      }
       else {
           System.out.println("Try again");

       }
   }
   while(running);
```

**The Difference**

In a `while loop`, the code can run `0-*` times. (0 to many). In a `do-while` loop, the code can run `1-*` times.

**Stack overflow ethos**

Try to think of this place as more of a last resort. I googled `do while loop java` and the first link was [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) which explains your issue perfectly. In future, perhaps you should use your own methods of research before you rely on ours.

**Edit for you**

A `for loop` is different, in that it will run `x` times. Like so:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
   System.out.println("Hello " + x);
}
   /**
    * OUTPUT:
    * Hello 0
    * Hello 1
    * Hello 2
    * Hello 3
    * Hello 4
    */
```

**Applying While loops to your problem**

The `do-while` loop has a conditional statement in it, inside the `while`.

```
do {
}
while(something is true)
```

Think of that as your `if statement`. Now you want that to be true, until the person has guessed `12` times. It only logically follows that you want to keep count of the number of guesses, so we'll introduce an `int` called `guesses`. And you only want `guesses` to reach `12` and no more, so this is where we'll go from.

```
do {
   // Some code goes here.
   guesses ++;
   // Increase the number of guesses if they got it wrong.
}
while(correct = false && guesses < 12)
```

What I've done is made up a variable called `correct`, that tells if the person got it right or not. And I increase the value in `guesses` each time they make a guess that's wrong. That means the loop will only stop if:

- The person guesses correctly
- The person had 12 attempts

Comment: One more question, how do I make it a counted loop, I have been trying to look it up but I can't find an answer

Comment: A counted loop? Like a `for` loop?

Comment: +1 for a detailed answer to a trivial question.

Comment: We haven't learned for loops yet in my class, so it can't be that, I am supposed to make it so you can only guess 12 times using while.

Comment: Well, if you know how many times the loop should run, you should `always` use a for loop, but if your teacher wants to teach you about while loops, I'll edit in a quick demo for you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  do{
          System.out.println("Guess your number");
          guess = scan.nextInt();

           if(guess == randomNumber) 
           {
               System.out.println("You are correct");
               break;
           }
           else if (guess > randomNumber)
           {
               System.out.println("Too high.");
           }              
           else if (guess < randomNumber)
           {
               System.out.println("Too low");
           }
           else 
           {
               System.out.println("Try again");
           }
    } while(running);
```

Comment: That's it.  By the way, since you're new, you should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

In you case it is pretty easy:

```
       boolean running = true;    
       do {
           System.out.println("Guess your number");
           guess = scan.nextInt();
           if(guess == randomNumber) {
                System.out.println("You are correct");
             break;
           }
           else if (guess > randomNumber){
               System.out.println("Too high.");
           }              
           else if (guess < randomNumber){
               System.out.println("Too low");
           }
           else {
               System.out.println("Try again");

           }
       } while (running)
```

In general you can transform an arbitrary *while loop* into *do-while loop* in following way:

```
while (condition) {
  ...
}
```

will become

```
if (condition) {
  do {
    ...
  } while (condition)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `break` when you guess the random number, then there's no point of using running as a control to break out of the loop.  I would simply change running when that happens.  Also, the line where you print out "Try again" will never be run, so you could remove that else block.  It would look like this.

```
do{
          System.out.println("Guess your number");
          guess = scan.nextInt();

          if(guess == randomNumber) 
          {
               System.out.println("You are correct");
               running = false;
          }
           else if (guess > randomNumber)
          {
               System.out.println("Too high.");
          }              
          else if (guess < randomNumber)
          {
               System.out.println("Too low");
          }
} while(running);
```